# PHP Keep on getting blank messages

Tags: php, jquery, forms, cloudflare

I have a very strange problem I have a form on my website which users fills out, everything works fine, with validation and the works, it's pretty solid, however I keep on getting 2 of these emails daily:

A new Enquiry has been received from http://www.cccccc.com.au. Please find details below and follow up:

```
Email : 
Phone Number : 
Event Type: 
Number Guests:
State: 
Suburb:
IP ADDRESS:173.245.50.130
Message:
```

Why is this why am I getting this?

I have traced the Ip and it comes from the US, which is weird since our website is targeted for Australia and most of our traffic comes from google adwords. ***However the ISP of the IP is cloudflare which is our hosting provider....?***

[image]

Any idea to why / how am I getting these blanks?

Here is my script....pretty nasic but it gets the message to us

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$eventType = $_POST['eventType'];
$nrGuests = $_POST['nrGuests'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$suburb = $_POST['suburb'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


    $to_email       = "xxxx@axxxxcom.au, xxxxx@xxxxxx.co.nz"; 

    $suburb     =   filter_var($_POST["suburb"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $subject        = "You Have a New Booking!";
    //Add booking INFO here;
    $message        = "A new Enquiry has been received from http://www.fingerfoods.com.au. Please find details below and follow up:";

    //email body
    $message_body = $message."\r\n\r\n".$name."\r\nEmail : ".$email."\r\nPhone Number : ". $mobile."\r\nEvent Type: ".$eventType."\r\nNumber Guests:".$nrGuests."\r\nState: ".$state."\r\nSuburb:".$suburb."\r\nIP ADDRESS:".$ip."\r\nMessage:".$msg;

    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$name.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);
    if($send_mail)
    {  
    echo '<h1 class="page-header">Enquiry Successfully submitted</h1>'; 
}
else{
    echo'<h1 class="page-header" style="color:RED">OOPS...SOMETHING WENT WRONG, PLEASE TRY AGAIN!</h1>';
}
        ?>
```

**THIS MAY SOUND A BIT STUPID BUT ANY IDEA WHY I AM I GETTING THESE BLANK EMAILS?? AS SEEN ABOVE**

Comment: Because you don't check for emptiness of input data? Because search robot visits your page and page is executed?

Comment: @u_mulder you can not submit the form without filling data even with javascript disabled....and it is the same IP coming from AMERICA we target only Australia but the Ip's isp is from cloudflare which is our hosting provider...?

Comment: Why I cannot submit? If this is your full script - than I can just visit this script and execute it. Who stops me?

Comment: WELL i JUST VISIT THE SCRIPT OR THE PAGE WHICH EXECUTES IT AND NOTHING HAPPENED......if that is what you mean? sorry I am desperate for help here

Comment: You have no letter received?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` gives the IP address from which the request was sent to the web server. This is typically the visitor's address, but in your case, it sounds like there is some kind of proxy sitting right before the web server that intercepts the requests, hence to the web server it appears as though the requests are originating from there.

Secondly, maybe you're not getting parameters values because you send GET requests and not POST, you can use `$_REQUEST`(get content of GET, POST, and COOKIE varialbe) instead of you don't distinguish between GET and POST requests.

[for more info. about requests kinds](http://shodor.org/~kevink/phpTutorial/nileshc_getreqpost.php)

And the most important thing, you MUST check inputs values, don't send form values unless they are not empty!

Comment: IM SORRY BUT THAT IS A BIT OF A NO ANWSER CLEARLY YOU CAN SEE I USE `POST` REQUESTS

Comment: No, I see that you're trying to get content from POST request(you won't see parameters in the url), If the form send GET (you'll see parameters in url) you won't get the content by POST request.. So try to use $_REQUEST like this:

$name = $_REQUEST ['name'];
$email = $_REQUEST ['email'];

Comment: I strongly disagree with your suggestion!

Comment: All forms are set at `method="post"`

Comment: Ok, then it's very important to check if inputs are not empty then user can submit the form.

if("" == trim($_POST['userName'])){
    $username = 'Anonymous';
}

Comment: One last thing, try to add name attribute to your inputs.

<input type="text" id="nameInput" name="name" placeholder="Enter name">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92574/discussion-between-firas-rassas-and-timothy-coetzee).